# How adding a capacitor reduces the signal gain to 1 in an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback

Here I can't understand how adding a capacitor reduces the signal gain to 1?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> *Here I can't understand how adding a capacitor reduces the signal gain
> to 1?*

The text you quoted is talking about \$\color{red}{\boxed{\text{DC only}}}\$ and therefore, putting a capacitor in series with R1 basically open circuits R1 (at DC) and, you are left with a simple unity gain non-inverting amplifier: -

[image]